# How to find the closest line from a convex hull to an arbitrary point

Tags: euclidean-geometry, control-theory, computational-geometry, convex-geometry, convex-hulls

I'm stuck into a control system problem with geometrical interpretation.
I have a set of linear equations $Ax\leq b$ which form a convex hull (more precisely a parallelogram), where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{4\times2}$ and $x\in \mathbb{R}^2$.

At each iteration I obtain a random point $[x_1^*,x_2^*]$. I'm sure that this point is out of the region formed by the lines that are normal to the faces of the parallelogram and pass through its vertices, i.e. I'm sure that the point $[x_1^*,x_2^*]$ is inside one of the 4 regions formed by the lines orthogonal to the faces of the parallelogram (Regions R2,R4,R6 and R8 in the annexed [Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZT8m.png)). My main problem is that I I need a fast(and efficient) way to find, at each iteration, the region in which the point $[x_1^*,x_2^*]$ is. Knowing this, I can calculate the closest point of the line (face of the parallelogram) to the point $[x_1^*,x_2^*]$, which will be the orthogonal projection of the point to the line.

My first idea was to find the points of the vertices(for example $[a_1,b_1],\ldots,[a_4,b_4]$) and use if statements such as:
$$if (a_1\leq x_1^*\leq a_2) \quad and \quad(b_1\leq x_2^*\leq b_2)$$
to find in which region the point $[x_1^*,x_2^*]$ is.

Can you guys help me with this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd probably just do an angle check via inner product. This is a constant-time check at every iteration. This is based on the following observation: Let $n_1$ and $n_2$ be the two vertices touching $R8$. Then for every $x\in R8$, $\langle x-n_1\,|\, n2-n_1\rangle \geq 0$ and $\langle x-n_2\,|\,n_2-n_1\rangle \geq 0$. Geometrically, this is saying that every point in your region must form an acute angle with the line segment. It looks geometrically like this should be an equivalence (since if you're in another region, at least one of the other angles must be obtuse.)

Comment: correction: I meant $\langle x-n_1\, |\, n_2-n_1\rangle \geq 0$ and $\langle x-n_2\, |\, n_1-n_2\rangle \geq 0$ means that the vector from $n_1$ to $x$ should form an acute angle with the parallelogram's line segment adjacent to the corresponding region (and same for $n_2$).

Comment: How do you know that the point $(x_1^*, x_2^*)$ is not in $R_1$, $R_3$, $R_5$, or $R_7$?

Comment: @J.Heller This is a constrained control system problem. The regions define how many constraints are active. If the point $(x_1^*,x_2^*)$ is in regions $R_1, R_3,\dots ,R_7$ two constraints will be active. So, the optimal result is the vertice of the convex hull. But if it is in the other regions, only one constraint is active, so the optimal results will be the point in the face of the parallelogram which is orthogonal to $(x_1^*,x_2^*)$.

Comment: @Zim, Thanks for your suggestion, I'll try that. I'm trying to develop an algorithm to identify which line form each region. For example, I have 4 lines $l_1,\dots, l_4$. I check which lines form vertices and label them $V_{a,b}$, which represents the vertice formed by the lines $l_a$ and $l_b$. After this I'll have something like this: $V_{1,2}$,  $V_{2,3}$,  $V_{3,4}$,  $V_{1,4}$. Then I check the indices of the vertices, if they have indices in common, for example, $V_{1,2}$,  $V_{2,3}$, I label that these vertices form a region. So, after this I think that I can apply your suggestion.

Comment: @LucianRibeiro Oh wait, if you're just trying to find the optimal solution, you can just project onto each line segment (constant time) and then measure the distance from the original point to each of the projections. The minimal-distance projection should be the projection onto the parallelogram (provided the initial point was outside of the set to start with). You only need the coordinates of each vertex to project onto the line segment. Would something like this solve your problem?

Comment: @Zim probably this would work. But my intuit is to implement this technique in a low-cost microcontroller. And also considering a small sampling time (the microcontroller must be able to calculate within this interval). So, I'm trying to remove all the online complex calculations. So, If I can rotulate the faces of the parallelogram offline and use some simple if statements online to find which region the point is, I can only calculate one projection instead 4. And also the calculation of the distance projection it will be not necessary, I supose.

Comment: @LucianRibeiro you're right, that route would likely be more cost effective. BTW, you may be able to re-use the inner product terms from the "if" statements for computing the projection onto the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $P$ is a point outside the quadrilateral and $A_i$ is vertex $i$ of the quadrilateral, then the projection of $P$ onto edge $i$ ($A_iA_{i+1}$) of the quadrilateral is
$$
  t_i = \frac{(P-A_i)\cdot (A_{i+1} - A_i)}{(A_{i+1}-A_i)\cdot (A_{i+1} - A_i)}.
$$
The real number $t_i$ is the position of the the nearest point to $P$ (call it $Q$) on line segment $A_iA_{i+1}$.  A value of $t_i=0$ means $Q=A_i$ and a value of $t_i=1$ means $Q=A_{i+1}$.  A value of $t_i$ outside the unit interval means the nearest point to $P$ on the line through $A_i$ and $A_{i+1}$ is outside line segment $A_i A_{i+1}$.

Let $\hat{v}_i = (A_{i+1} - A_i) / |A_{i+1} - A_i|$ be the unit direction vector of edge $i$.  If the vertices of the quadrilateral are in counter-clockwise orientation, then the outward pointing normal for edge $i$ is $\hat{v}_i$ rotated by -90 degrees about the $z$ axis or $\hat{n}_i = (\hat{v}_{iy}, -\hat{v}_{ix})$.  The equation of the line containing edge $i$ can be written as $\hat{n}_i \cdot x + c_i = 0$ (where $c_i = -\hat{n}_i\cdot A_i$).  The signed distance of a point $P$ from this line is $\hat{n}_i\cdot P + c_i$.

Using at most three projections and signed distance computations, you can find the region containing $P$.  You know that $P$ is in the region outside edge $i$ if $0\le t_i \le 1$ and $\hat{n}_i \cdot P + c_i \ge 0$.  If you compute all the quantities $\hat{n_i}$, $c_i$, and $(A_{i+1} - A_i) / (A_{i+1}-A_i) \cdot (A_{i+1}-A_i)$ "offline", the only computation you need to do "online" is at most 6 two-dimensional dot products.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. Nice and clear explanation. I'll try to implement that!